# Place second currency in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, currency

Because of situation in country there is need to put the second price in EUR in the shop at the same time like:

**Price:**

*5 Ls*

*7.12 €*

Is there some way to show the second price in the page? Right now page use prestashop 1.4.4.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Javascript Currency Converter. Unless your payment processor accepts multiple currencies you have to be clear that any currencies other than the one you actually take payment in, are just an approximation. Because any exchange rate converter you use won't use identical rates to your payment processor. Ones that I have come across are.

http://www.yourcurrencyconverter.com/

https://openexchangerates.org/

PS - often people will recommend using yahoo or google as they both have a exchange rate API. However both of those are not allowed to be used for commercial use.